# Creating categories while importing via CSV

Tags: plugins, wp-insert-post, csv

I have a CSV that I am importing via a custom plugin I made. This will create a CPT that has a few ACF fields. This CPT is called Formula, and it has a taxonomy associated with it called formula_type. I am able to successfully import around ~300 posts, but I have a column in the CSV for categories. I am curious how I can create categories while I am parsing the CSV.

For example, while parsing, the loop hits a category called Diuretics. It creates a category for this and adds it into `wp_insert_post`, however if it is created, it is assigned to the post. Here is what my loop looks like currently:

tldr: With my current loop, how can I create categories that are new, and add categories to my post if they have already been created.

```
foreach($records as $results) {

        $post = array(
            'post_title'    => $results['drug_name'],
            'post_type'     => 'formula',
            'post_status'   => 'publish',
        );

        $post_id = wp_insert_post($post);
        update_field( 'field_5cfe5ac146838', $results['indication'], $post_id ); // indication
        update_field( 'field_5cfe629f3693b', $results['amount'], $post_id ); // amount
        update_field( 'field_5d0d086c5d916', 'true', $post_id ); // imported
        update_field( 'field_5d0d0998796cd', $results['drug_id'], $post_id ); // drug ID

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this by checking if the term exists, and then using `tax_input` in `wp_insert_post()`

```
// Check if the category exists
$category_term = term_exists(trim($category), 'formula_types', 0);

// Create category if it doesn't exist
if (!$category_term) {
    $category_term = wp_insert_term(trim($category), 'formula_types', array('parent' => 0));
}
array_push($formattedCategories, (int)$category_term['term_taxonomy_id']);

$post = array(
    'post_title'    => $results['drug_name'],
    'post_type'     => 'formula',
    'post_status'   => 'publish',
    'tax_input'    => array(
            'formula_types' =>
            $formattedCategories,
    )
);
```